# How to evaluate the derivative of $e^{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I evaluate the derivative of the following function?

$$
f(x) = e^{e^x}
$$

Which kind of function is it? Exponential?

I tried to use the fact that $[e^x]' = e^x$ but I can't think about any strategy to solve $e^{e^x}$.

Comment: [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) works here.

Comment: Straightforward:  ${d f(x) \over d x} = e^{x+e^x}$.

Comment: Why a question already solved is put on hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $g(x) = e^x$, we have $f(x) = g \big( g(x) \big)$.  Now apply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$f'(x) = g' \big(g(x) \big) \cdot g'(x)$$

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this calculation is the following: Let $y= e^{e^x}$. Notice that $\ln y = e^x$. Taking the derivatives on both sides of this identity we obtain
$$\frac{y'}{y} = e^x$$
and therefore
$$y'=ye^x = e^{e^x}e^x.$$

Comment: Clever!  +1. [and here's some junk for the min char limit]

Answer (score 1):

The answers above certainly do the job but I think it  may help to write explicitly what you are calculating

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^{e^x} = \frac{d \; (e^{e^x})}{d \;e^x} \frac{d (e^x)}{dx}.  $$

The first term

$$ \frac{d \; (e^{e^x})}{d \;(e^x)} = \frac{d \; (e^{f(x)})}{d \;f(x)} = e^{f(x)} = e^{e^x},  $$

and the second term is obvious so

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^{e^x} = e^{e^x} e^x = e^{e^x + x}. $$

Answer (score 0):

$y=e^{e^x}\Rightarrow \ln y= e^x\Rightarrow \frac{y'}{y}=e^x$

then $y'=ye^x\Rightarrow y'=e^{e^x}e^x=e^{e^x+x}$